# Element UI, passing id to table column with checkbox

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

Is there a way to pass id to `el-table-column` with `selection` type? I've tried passing a slot, but then checkbox is not rendering. Here is the code:

```
<el-table-column>
    <template slot-scope="scope" v-if="scope.row">
      <div :id="`column-${scope.row.name}`">{{ `reports-${scope.row.name}` }}</div>
    </template>
  </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column prop="selected" align="center" type="selection" class-name="checkbox-column">
</el-table-column>
```

First column getting id via scoped slot.

Comment: Ping me on skype, let's figure out. Skype ID: syed_haroon

Comment: @Syed Thank a lot for your time! Formatter didn't work out for me and I ended up catching row name from scoped slot :) So in my first column instead of returning a string directly, I pass it to a function:
  `<div>{{ getRowName(scope.row.name) }}</div>`
and in this function I store this name to a variable and passing to the second column as a class-name

Comment: UPD: my solution not worked out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ID` if you are okay with `class` then use `cell-class-name`

In your `template`

```
<el-table your-attrs ...  :cell-class-name="cellClassName">
```

In your `script`

```
methods: {
  cellClassName({row, column, rowIndex, columnIndex}) {
    if (columnIndex === 1) return `checkbox-${rowIndex}`;
  }
}
```